# 3rd-Eden memcached append json data

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, memcached

I am running a local instance of memcached and using 3rd-Eden memcached library to interface with it. The cache is used to store some JSON data, but sometimes I want to append new fields to the objects, as only the needed information is pushed to the memory, so what I do is creating a new JSON object containing the new fields, say:

```
var obj = {
    bio: "blah"
}
```

and then call the `memcached.append(key, obj, callback_here)`. The problem is that this object is concatenated to the previous one, invalidating the JSON, so when I try to retrieve the stored data, I get the following error message:

```
[{"service":"service1","id":"abc"},{"service":"service2","id":"zed"}]}{"bio":"bl
                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

I know that I can re-upload the whole new object, but this way seems to be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the append function appends a **string** to the stored value as it can't handle any other data types. So when you append, you will have to do JSON.stringify() on the value and add any commas necessary to create a valid JSON.

I personally get and re-set the whole object if i want to make changes to it.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: You're probably right. I'm doing the same here, but I'm using the [merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge) package for handling the objects merging.